# How to set dtoverlay @ config.txt?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, lirc

No.1 - I have one rasperry pi 3 where hyperion (ambilight) is running.

No.2 - And one rasperry pi 3 where I have an IR transmitter (with lirc) for sending commands to the tv.

I need to have both functions on one raspberry. I tried to let the the IR transmiter to run on raspberry #1, but I dont know how to set the dtoverlay.

**rasp #1** (hyperion) 
dtoverlay is set to wg1-gpio.
Used pins: 9, 19, 23

**rasp #2** (lirc) 
dtoverlay is set to lirc-rpi.
Used pins: 17, 11, 6

How do I have to set the dtoverlay? (I tried lirc-rpi and wg1-gpio already)

TIA

Comment: I have two dtoverlay statements in my config.txt. gpios statements follow each dtoverlay.

Comment: so I can set it like this? dtoverlay=wg1-gpio,lirc-rpi .. I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @PaulF8080, I tried with dtoverlay=wg1-gpio,lirc-rpi  
but now I get following error. Lirc0 will not be found
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mode2 -d /dev/lirc0
mode2: could not get file information for /dev/lirc0
mode2: default_init(): No such file or directory`

Comment: I don't see two dtoverlay lines.

Comment: It worked know with only dtoverlay=lirc-rpi and I dont know why. But it works :)

Comment: Your question is wrong. If you change two parts of the device tree you need two overlays. There is no one and only overlay. I know it is a lot of trouble to type dtoverlay twice, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It worked now with only dtoverlay=lirc-rpi and I dont know why. But it works :)

Comment: Can you please accept your answer so it is closed and will not be bumped again to the homepage?